# 'hg in --branch' exact name comparison

Tags: mercurial, branch

Using mercurial command:

```
hg in --branch XXX
```

I'll get not only XXX branch new commits, but new commits for all other branches which names start with 'XXX', such as 'XXX-test', 'XXX-new-case', 'XXX-huge-data' and so on. The same problem exists with `hg pull` command.

Is there a simple way to get the exact branch that I need?

Of course, I can use `hg in` to get all changesets, check their branch names, filter changeset ids for my branch and than request pull only that changesets. But this way doesn't look like a simple one.

Answer (score 0):

For `--branch` option **expected value** is full name of branch, because `-b` is

> a specific branch you would like to pull

You *have to know it*. Period

Comment: Yes, I know the full name of a branch. My question was not about it.

Answer (score 0):

Really, I was just confusing seeing other branch names using `hg in --branch XXX` command. But the reason was there was merges from branches XXX-yyy, XXX-zzz and so on to the branch XXX, so the changesets from those branches now exist in the XXX branch.

So, really, `hg in --branch XXX` gives me only changesets existing in the XXX branch, but some of those chagesets show me names of branches they have been merged from.